# ORing an undefined value from localStorage when passing arguments

Tags: javascript, local-storage, undefined

If I do this:

```
localStorage['a'] = undefined
alert(localStorage['a'] || 20)
```

"undefined" is alerted - WHY?

```
var a = undefined
alert(a || 20)
```

now 20 is alerted.

```
localStorage.clear()
alert(localStorage['a'] || 20)
```

here 20 as well... and I checked localStorage['a'] is undefined... just like in the first case when I set it to undefined manually... so why different results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

localStorage stores strings and converts what you pass to strings, so

```
localStorage['a'] = undefined
```

sets the string `"undefined"` as value in localStorage. It doesn't remove the key and it doesn't set its value as `undefined`.

And of course `"undefined"` isn't falsy so `"undefined"||20` is `"undefined"`.

To remove a value, use

```
localStorage.removeItem('a');
```

As an aside be careful to the fact that if you set

```
localStorage['a'] = 20
```

then you don't get `20` when calling `localStorage['a']` but the string `"20"`. When you want to get a not null number with a default value, you may do this :

```
var num = parseInt(localStorage['a'])||20;
```

Comment: really? interesting... and strange. Why is that not a syntactic error... anyway when I try with `localStorage['a'] = null` it also behaves strangely... it alerts "null" -> so is here the same? a string "null" is set? really didn't know that. Is this the consequence of localStorage? because with normal javascript variables (second case) it works as expected.

Comment: @DavidKrmpotic localStorage saves the data on disk so it only supports strings. Sure it could do JSON behind the scenes but that would make it much slower when JSON is not needed.

Comment: localStorage only stores strings. So it converts `null` to `"null"` and `undefined` to `"undefined"`.

Comment: @Esailija and even JSON is limited compared to the possible values you have in JavaScript (NaN, infinites, cyclic properties, references to native objects, etc.).

Comment: @dystroy yeah that is probably the more plausible explanation :P

Comment: Oh ok great, I get it now... My last question: what would be the best way to check if the key is set? `localStorage['a'] === undefined`?

Comment: @DavidKrmpotic `localStorage.getItem("a") == null` for example